# Custom table in HTML5

Tags: html

I need a table like in the picture [image]. I've tried it but I can't do exactly what I want. Here is the code I've wrotten:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
    .tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;} 
    .tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;} 
    .tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;} 
    .tg .tg-yw4l{vertical-align:top} 
</style> 
    <table class="tg">   
    <tr>
            <th class="tg-yw4l" rowspan="2"></th>
            <th class="tg-yw4l"></th>
            <th class="tg-yw4l"></th>   
    </tr>   
    <tr>
            <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
            <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>   
    </tr>   
    <tr>
            <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
            <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
            <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>   
    </tr> 
    </table>
```

Comment: Are you doing a layout using a table? Or is this really for tabular data?

Comment: It's a layout to add some images and dates! Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just use Bootstrap? Bootstrap offers containers to do just that and is much simpler and efficient than doing itself.

Comment: @SonneVA Then you probably should use some layout technique that CSS offers you. (Unless you are doing e-mail templates for Outlook)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use a nested table to achieve your layout - if you insist on using tables

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: center;
}

.tg {
    height: 400px;
}

.tg table {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table class="tg">   
    <tr>
            <th class="tg-yw4l no-pad" rowspan="3">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>td</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>td</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </th>
            <th class="tg-yw4l">th</th>
            <th class="tg-yw4l">th</th>   
    </tr>   
    <tr>
            <td class="tg-yw4l">td</td>
            <td class="tg-yw4l">td</td>   
    </tr>   
    <tr>
            <td class="tg-yw4l">td</td>
            <td class="tg-yw4l">td</td>   
    </tr> 
</table>
```